# Is it necessary to save the FPU state here?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, cdecl

I wrote a simple cooperative multi-threading library. Currently I always save and restore the fpu state with `fxsave` / `fxrstor` when switching to a new context. But is this necessary in the cdecl calling convention?

As a simple example:

```
float thread_using_fpu(float x)
{
    float y = x / 2; // do some fpu operation
    yield();         // context switch, possibly altering fpu state.
    y = y / 2;       // another fpu operation
    return y;
}
```

May the compiler make any assumptions about the FPU state after the call to `yield()`?

Comment: No, the usual convention mandates FPU state be empty upon entry and exit (unless used for return value obviously).

Comment: Thanks, do you happen to have a source for this? I couldn't find much about this myself. Not having to save and restore a 512-byte buffer every time would really help improve performance, and I want to be 100% sure this won't cause any issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the The [*SYSTEM V APPLICATION BINARY INTERFACE Intel386TM Architecture Processor Supplement*](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf),  page 3-12:

> %st(0): If the function does not return a floating-point value, then this
>          register must be empty. This register must be empty before
>          entry to a function.
>
> %st(1) through %st(7):
>   Floating-point scratch registers have no specified role in the
>   standard calling sequence. These registers must be empty before entry
>   and upon exit from a function.

Thus, you do not need to context switch them.

Another, [newer version](https://uclibc.org/docs/psABI-i386.pdf) says this:

> The CPU shall be in x87 mode upon entry to a function. Therefore, every function that uses the MMX registers is required to issue an
>   emms or femms instruction after using MMX registers, before returning
>   or calling another function. [...]
>       The control bits of the MXCSR register are callee-saved (preserved across calls), while the status bits are caller-saved (not preserved).
>   The x87 status word register is caller-saved, whereas the x87 control
>   word is callee-saved.
>   [...] All x87 registers are caller-saved, so callees that make use of the MMX registers may use the faster femms instruction.

So, you may need to save the control word.

Answer (score 3):

No.  You don't have to do any saving of the state.  If one thread is in the middle of a floating point calculation where there is, for example, a denormalized flag set, and that thread is interrupted, then when it resumes the O/S or kernel will set the flags, just like it will restore other registers.  Likewise, you don't have to worry about it in a yield().

Edit: If you are doing your own context switching, it is possible you would need to save the precision and rounding control flags if you need to set them to non-default values.  Otherwise, again you're fine.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm doing my own context switching, not using OS-managed threads.